# moment.js add/subtract days without affecting the original date

Tags: momentjs

How do you add or subtract days to a default date using moment.js?

I am trying to get the start and end dates of the week like below:

```
const current = moment.tz('2016-03-04', 'America/Los_Angeles');
const startOfWeek = current.startOf('isoWeek').weekday(0);
const endOfWeek = current.endOf('isoWeek').weekday(6);
```

When calling `endOfWeek`, I am getting the expected value. 
However, my problem is that `startOfWeek` is overridden by the `endOfWeek` value.

I wanted to get the value of both `startOfWeek` and `endOfWeek`

Comment: try this `moment().add(7, 'days'); `.Also go through [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/)

Comment: this is still overriding the value of startOfWeek

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 65):

You just need to clone the moment first before modifying it.  Use either `current.clone().whatever...` or `moment(current).whatever...`. They both do the same thing.

This is necessary because moments are *mutable*.

Answer (score 8):

You need to clone the value of current and then perform the operations:

```
const current = moment.tz('2016-03-04', 'America/Los_Angeles');
const startOfWeek = current.clone().startOf('isoWeek').weekday(0);
const endOfWeek = current.endOf('isoWeek').weekday(6);
```

Comment: How to get a Date object from that formatted moment?

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem by getting the format of the `startOfWeek` and saving it in a variable. Then from the new variable, I convert it to a moment instance and from here, I get the `endOfWeek` value.

```
const current = moment.tz('2016-03-04', 'America/Los_Angeles');
const startOfWeek = current.startOf('isoWeek').weekday(0);

const startOfWeekConvert = startOfWeek.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

const endOfWeek = startOfWeekConvert.endOf('isoWeek').weekday(6);
```

I am now able to get both the start and end dates of the week at the same time.

Comment: This won't work.  The `startOfWeekConvert` variable is a *string*, because you created it with `format`.  Therefore, it has no `endOf` function.